# “Remember Me” functionality in a PhoneGap application

Tags: cordova

I am new to PhoneGap development. My PhoneGap application has a login page and I need to implement a "Remember Me" option into this login page. I have no idea about this functionality anyone can help me. I want to some sample code about this functionality.

Please refer my tried code following,

```
function checkPreAuth() {
    /* console.log("checkPreAuth");*/
    if(window.localStorage.getItem("remember") == true)
    {
        if(window.localStorage.getItem("username") != undefined && window.localStorage.getItem("password") != undefined) {

            var form = $("#loginForm");
            $("#Username", form).val(window.localStorage.getItem("username"));
            $("#Password", form).val(window.localStorage.getItem("password"));
            $("#remember_me", form).attr('checked', true).checkboxradio("refresh");
    handleLogin();
        }
    }
}

$(document).on('pageinit', '#loginPage', function(){
               //getTimezoneName();
                $('#submitButton').click(function(e){
                                         e.preventDefault();
                                         var u = $("#Username").val();
                                         var p = $("#Password").val();
handleLogin();
});
});

function handleLogin()
{
    var form = $("#loginForm");
    $("#submitButton",form).attr("disabled","disabled");
    var u = $("#Username", form).val();
    var p = $("#Password", form).val();
    if(u != '' && p!= '')
    {        
        $.ajax({
               url: 'http://samplewebsite.com/API/login_api',
               type: 'post',
               dataType: 'json',
               data: $('form#loginForm').serialize(),
               crossDomain: 'true',
               success: function(data)
               {
               if(data)
               {
               //window.localStorage.setItem("key", "value");
               // var keyname = window.localStorage.key(i);
               if($("#remember_me").is(':checked'))
               {
               window.localStorage.setItem("remember", $("#remember_me").is(':checked'));
               }
               window.localStorage.setItem("userId", data.id);
               window.localStorage.setItem("username", u);
               window.localStorage.setItem("password", p);

               $.mobile.changePage("Inbox.html");
               }
               else
               {
               navigator.notification.alert("Your login failed", function() {});               
               }              

               },error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {               
               navigator.notification.alert("Your login failed",null);
               }

               });
    }
    else
    {
        navigator.notification.alert("You must enter a username and password", function() {},"");       
    }    
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. In questions you need to show some evidence of what you have researched and what you have tried, along with any issues you found, rather than expecting someone to do everything for you.

Answer (score 2):

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Car</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>                   
    </head>
    <body>
      <div data-role="page" id="page_login" >
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Login</h1>
        </div><!-- /header -->
        <div role="main" class="ui-content" id="content">
            <form id="frm_login">
                <input type="text" value="" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username" />
                <input type="password" value="" id="vPassword" name="vPassword" placeholder="Password" />
                <input type="checkbox" name="remember_me" id="remember_me" class="custom check" />
                <label for="remember_me" class="check-label" id="lbl_rem_me">Remember Me</label>

                <a href="" class="ui-btn" data-transition="slide" data-role="none" id="btn_log">Login</a>
            </form>
        </div>           
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>
$(document).on("pageshow", "#page_login", function(e){
    if(window.localStorage["username_rem"] != undefined && window.localStorage["password_rem"] != undefined) 
    {
        if(window.localStorage["username_rem"] != "" && window.localStorage["password_rem"] != ""){                 
          $('#frm_login :input[id=username]').val(window.localStorage["username_rem"]);
          $('#frm_login :input[id=vPassword]').val(window.localStorage["password_rem"]);
          $("#remember_me").attr('checked', true).checkboxradio("refresh");
       }                
    }
})

$(document).on("click", "#btn_log", function(e){
    var u = $('#frm_login :input[id=username]').val();
    var p = $('#frm_login :input[id=vPassword]').val();
    if($("#remember_me").is(':checked')){               
      window.localStorage["username_rem"] = u;
      window.localStorage["password_rem"] = p;                        
    }else{
      window.localStorage["username_rem"] = "";
      window.localStorage["password_rem"] = ""; 
    }
})      
</script>
```

Comment: I had used your sample .js and replaced this

Comment: I had used your sample javascript. It is maintaining the localstorage value and login with out username and password,but if user clicked remember me and close the app without logout and again if he open the app,login screen is come to display.I need to hide the login screen if user is in remember me.Please help me to solve this.